# When i try to run/compile a java file with Geany it spits out an error

Tags: java, geany

i wanted to learn java, and for text editor i use geany, i wanted to run this code:

```
public class Main {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
                System.out.print("Java!");
        }
}
```

But when i run it, it gives me this error:

Error: Could not find or load main class main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main

I installed the latest java se, setted up the enviroment variables, and edited the compile and launch options for java in geany. Nothing works.

Comment: What's the name of the file? How exactly are you compiling and running it?

Comment: The class is called `Main`, not `main`. Classes are case-sensitive